# How to determine if a function has monotonicity in a certain interval

Tags: functions

Determine whether the following function monotonically decreases in the interval`[0, 2 \[Pi]/3]`

The function is:

```
f[x_] = Cos[Abs[x]] - 2 Abs[Sin[x]]
```

draw a function image

[image]

It is not possible to accurately determine from the image whether the function monotonically decreases within this interval`[0, 2 \[Pi]/3]`
.

Is there an accurate method to determine whether a function has monotonicity in a certain interval?

Comment: "It is not possible to accurately determine from the image whether the function monotonically decreases" - if you are ok with a visual result, then zoom in closer in your plot. If a visual result is not sufficient, then perhaps the question becomes more about the math rather than about Mathematica.

Comment: I hope to use Mathematica to solve this mathematical problem.

Comment: @MarcoB Mathematica is able to solve such problems, and I have found a solution myself.

Comment: You can find where the derivative vanishes and compare the value there and at the right endpoint. `In[721]:= f[x_] = Cos[RealAbs[x]] - 2 RealAbs[Sin[x]];
zder = SolveValues[D[f[x], x] == 0 && 0 < x < 2*Pi/3, x][[1]]
N[f[zder] - f[2*Pi/3]]

Out[722]= 2 ArcTan[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])]

Out[723]= -0.00401717` This means it is increasing near that end of the domain. (Alternatively, check that the second derivative does not vanish and in fact is positive where the first does; this shows the curve bends back up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function reaches a minimum value right before $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, so it is not monotonically decreasing in the range $0\leq x\leq \frac{2\pi}{3}$:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := Cos[RealAbs[x]] - 2 RealAbs[Sin[x]]

critical = Solve[{f'[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi/3}, x]
(* Out: {{x -> 2 ArcTan[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])]}} *)

Plot[
  {f[x], f'[x]}, {x, 0, Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3], Automatic},
  GridLines -> {{{2 Pi/3, Directive[Opacity[1], Black]}}, None},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Red, Point[{x, f[x]} /. critical]}
]
```

[image: plots of function, its derivative, and the critical point]

Answer (score 0):

Use FunctionMonotonicity

```
FunctionMonotonicity[{Cos[Abs[x]] - 2 Abs[Sin[x]], 
  0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi]/3}, x]
```

get the result:

```
Indeterminate
```

neither non-decreasing nor non-increasing

[image]